# Bootstrap wysiwyg editor button relocation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

[image]I was wondering if anyone has any idea on how to move a button from the menu in bootstrap wysiwyg editor, to another location.  Picture the image insert button here on stack overflow.  How could you move the image button to the bottom right (similar to social networks) below the textarea and put in a "Add Image" button or something similar. Basically relocate any button out of the bar so you didn't have the standard bar layout. Thanks

Comment: What editor? There's no editor included with Bootstrap. Add some resources, a fiddle, or some code... this question is impossible to answer without it.

Comment: I'm using the http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/ editor for bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I get your question correctly but take a look at the image below.. Is this what you are  trying to say?

If so then take a look at the inspect element below the site and add a `pull-right` to class `wysihtml5-toolbar`. this makes the `ul` float to right

[image]